# How to find string length in C without strlen() or searching for NULL terminator

Tags: c, binary-data

I need to count the length of a string encoded using Huffman compression. It may have '\0' characters so `strlen()` or any other function that searches for the NULL terminator won't work. How can I determine the length of such a string?

Comment: Could you show us your logic , so that we find where the bug is

Comment: the bug is in the design. Either length needs to be stored in the encryption step and tracked, or a special sequence of characters needs to be selected to define the end.

Comment: `NULL` is a pointer. ASCII nul (`'\0'`) is a character. You solve the problem by having the encryption algorithm tell you how many bytes the encrypted data is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible. Go on a field and walk **until the end**. There will be nothing different than the rest of the field to mark the end.

- Compute the length before encryption (encryption shouldn't typically change it)
- Use a character that may not appear in the string (if there is one) as terminator

#### EDIT

*The OP mentioned he is using Huffman for compression.*

In this case you should have the compression function return the size of the compressed string.

Comment: encrypting stuff **may** change the length.

Comment: @Alex Thanks for the comment. I don't know much encryption, can you point out major algorithms that change the length ?

Comment: its assignment work My senior told me its not good programming if u count the stringlength using null character logic and strlen(

Comment: @Sam_k That makes you his vassal, right ? So he is obliged to give you *consilium et auxilium*. Or is it the other way around ?

Comment: @cnicutar he told me if in your function '\0' or NULL ASCII means 0. than how to handle this scenario

Comment: @Sam_k What algorithm do you use ?

Comment: @cnicutar i have to implemented Huffman Algo. in that there is String that will be compressed after huffman encoding. so my senior told me why are You using String  functions its will not work if are input string having NULL Character so how to find length of string without strlen and NULL character logic

Comment: @Sam_k First of all Huffman is used for compression, NOT encryption. Second, the compression function itself should return the length of the output.

Comment: @cnicutar: all block ciphers use blocks of fixed length. if your string isn't a multiple of the block-size most library calls will automatically pad your input.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a struct with an int for length and a char pointer to store your strings. Use malloc to allocate memory and memcpy for manipulating the strings.

Comment: Use `size_t` for length instead of `int`.

Answer (score 2):

The important question is what do you use to encrypt? If this encryption library doesn't change the length of the string you should know how large the string was before because you could `strlen()` it before.

If the library changes the length you will have to pass a buffer to it and tell the library its size. The library then must return if the call was successful (i.e.: the buffer was big enough) and how big the target is.

Note: if you use a block cipher you are only allowed to input blocks of a certain length (not shorter or longer) and the result is of a fixed size buffer - in the case of openssl there is a macro `#define` that states the block length and the length of the result.

code sharing would be appreciated here.

Answer (score 1):

In C, a string is an array of characters terminated with a binary 0. If you have 0s scattered through your string, it is no longer a string.

In your encryption process, you need to store the length of the string, which is now not a string but binary data. You could also define a magic sequence of characters that terminates the encrypted string, but then you have to make sure that the magic sequence is never embedded in the encrypted data.

Comment: but how to find out first time string length without this function and this logic..

Comment: its assignment work My senior told me its not good programming if u count the stringlength using null character logic and strlen()

Comment: When you encrypt the string you should get the length of the encrypted data. Read the documentation for the encryption method you are using..

Comment: But how to find length of encrypted data without NULL character logic..Thanks

Comment: When you encrypt/compress the string, store the length of the compressed *data* in the variable `data_length`. Then you will be able to find the length of the encrypted data in `data_length`.